# Create button in Powerpoint 2013 ribbon that opens a hyperlink

Tags: vba, ribbon, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I'd like to create a button that automatically opens a hyperlink from Powerpoint.

It's easy enough to create a hyperlink in Powerpoint (Insert -> Hyperlink) and then click on that hyperlink.

I want to skip this whole process and just be able to have a button that opens a hyperlink rather than having a hyperlink in my presentation that needs to be clicked.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far? What were the results? http://www.howtogeek.com/142270/create-a-customized-tab-on-the-office-2013-ribbon/, http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/can-i-customize-the-ribbon-HA010227754.aspx, http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html, etc.

Comment: Do you want a ribbon button that goes to one specific hyperlink or do you want a ribbon button that opens a selected hyperlink in the presentation?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 ... I posted an example with some code that solves this. However, it only opens the link in Internet Explorer; it'd be much better to have it done in Chrome. Also, I'd love to have a solution that creates a link to open a PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution... the only problem with this one is that it opens in Internet Explorer instead of Chrome. Additionally, it would be great to adapt it to handle opening PDFs.

The XML for the button would be something like:

```
                    <button id="myButton" label="Open Hyperlink" 
                        imageMso="HyperlinkInsert"
                        size="large" 
                        onAction="openHyperlink"
                        />
```

And the callback would be like:

```
Sub openHyperlink(control As IRibbonControl)
    'your code that opens the hyperlink goes in here, something like:
    Dim ie as Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://google.com"

End Sub
```